# Update more widgets from BroadcastReceiver using RemoteViews

Tags: android, widget, broadcastreceiver, remoteview

I followed these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18236800/824963 to make my broadcastreceiver work.

Actually all alarmmanagers are working fine, but each time onReceive is called all widget are updated with the same data

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
    {       
        final String address = intent.getStringExtra("mykey");
        ...
        final RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget); 

        // downloading data
        ...
        // decoding data
        ...

        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.mykey, newvalue);

        ComponentName thiswidget = new ComponentName(context, AppWidgetProvider.class);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thiswidget, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your call for update app widget?

Comment: Should i call onUpdate of AppWidgetProvider from onReveive?

Comment: Does your onUpdate not get called automatically?

Comment: i need to update the widgets every 3 minutes, so i setted android:updatePeriodMillis="0"

Comment: updatePeriodMillis will only update once every 30 minutes even if you set it to be less than that.

Comment: But i need to update my widgets every 3 minutes... For this reason i'm using alarmmanager

Comment: Can you show the code where you would do something like `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widget, views);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36563/discussion-between-user824963-and-ryan-huang)

Comment: I edited the first post